# Android alarmmanger gets called in different time?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am working on Android AlarmManager and i found one issue in my code. The Alarm manager gets called in different time as well , i don't find what's the reason , i gave alarm at 7:10 AM but it gets called whenever i open the app in different time like 3:10 PM , 4:30 PM etc.

**MyCode :**

```
public void setAlarm(){

      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
      calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
      calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
      calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
      calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 1);
      calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
      calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
      calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM);

    Intent intent = new Intent(appContext, MyAlarmManager.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(appContext, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) appContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),  AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
```

**MyAlarmManager.java**

```
public class MyAlarmManagerextends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    setAlarm();

 } }
```

So , this is the above code , please let me know what's wrong in the code and suggest me some solution.

Comment: Is your initialisation from a service or an activity?

Comment: No , it is in a singleton class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the alarm is set in the past (when you set it anytime after 07:10 AM) So, you have to add 1 day if it is past 07:10 AM today.

**Explanation -**

Suppose it is 8 AM today and you are setting an alarm for 07:10, it sets an alarm for the same day 07:10 AM which is already past, hence it goes off whenever you open the app

**Solution -**

Option 1 - Either set date, month and year too like -

```
calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, date);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
```

Option 2 - Check what is the current time, if current time > the alarm time, add one day to the alarm

```
//If you are past 07:10 AM then 
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
```

Comment: so , where will i modified? please let me know

Comment: @animation123 added some logic to the answer, try to implement any of the solution which suits your need

Comment: Thank you so much , i will update the answer in the post

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

This might happen if you are using Android version Marshmallow or higher. It is called **Doze Mode**

Doze Mode is implemented to save the battery by delaying stuff like `AlarmManager`, `SyncAdapter`, `JobScheduler`. Refer to [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N72ksDKrX6c) to find out more about Doze Mode